# How do I match this url pattern in filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Given this code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/run/{alias}/synchronous")
public String start(@PathVariable String test)  {
    return "ok";
}
```

I want to match the url in the requestmapping method. I have tried this without success.

```
registration.addUrlPatterns("/run/*/synchronous");
```

Comment: Did you try with ** ?

Comment: The `@RequestMapping(path = "/run/{alias}/synchronous")`
works for me.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes I have tried that /run/**/synchronous

Comment: try `/run/*?/synchronous` and `/run/.*?/synchronous` to make `*` non-greedy

Comment: @Kartik I tried but still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I use these codes to handle GET and POST method.

```
@GetMapping("/run/{alias}/synchronous")
@PostMapping("/run/{alias}/synchronous")
```

Comment: So how would I match the postmapping url in the filter?

Comment: What regex would I use?

Comment: Hm, I am afraid that I don't understand your question. Please give me some context.

Comment: please check my another answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? Add some "key" to @PathVariable because your variable "test" is different to "alias". Check this link [Request Mapping in Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping)

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/run/{alias}/synchronous")
public String start(@PathVariable("alias") String test){
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: What I am asking is what string do I put here: `registration.addUrlPatterns("/run/*/synchronous");`. It needs to be a regex

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the servlet spec does not allow for wildcards in the middle of the string.  I'm looking for the same answer as you are... for calling FilterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns().  I'm looking into how to make my own Filter that takes in a regex or an endsWith.